# Problems with pipe

Tags: c++, shell, fork, pipe

I'm trying to create a simple shell, but I can't seem to make this function work. I can't find anything wrong with it. I'm testing a simple command, like "ls | sort", but I get no output at all.

```
void execute(std::vector<Command *> cmds)
{
    int inp[2], out[2];
    pipe(inp);
    pipe(out);
    int status, fd = 0;
    bool switcher = true;

    for (auto i = 0; i < cmds.size(); i++)
    {
        auto pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1) {

            throw std::runtime_error("Could not fork.");

        } else if (pid == 0) {

            if (i == 0) {
                dup2(inp[1], 1);
            } else if (i == cmds.size() - 1) {
                dup2(out[0], 0);
            } else {
                if (switcher) {
                    dup2(inp[0], 0);
                    dup2(out[1], 1);
                    switcher = false;
                } else {
                    dup2(inp[1], 1);
                    dup2(out[0], 0);
                    switcher = true;
                }
            }

            close(inp[0]);
            close(inp[1]);
            close(out[0]);
            close(out[1]);

            if(execvp(cmds[i]->args_char[0], cmds[i]->args_char.data()) < 0) {
                std::cout << "Command not found." << std::endl;
                exit(1);
            }

        } else {

            close(inp[0]);
            close(inp[1]);
            close(out[0]);
            close(out[1]);

            wait(&status);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `Command` struct:

```
struct Command {
    int identity;
    std::vector<char *> args_char;
    std::vector<std::string> args_string;
    bool redirectin;
    bool redirectout;
    std::string filename;

    Command(int id, std::vector<char *> cmds_char, std::vector<std::string> cmds_string)
    {
        identity = id;
        args_string = cmds_string;
        args_char = cmds_char;
        redirectin = false;
        redirectout = false;

        for (auto i = 0; i < args_string.size(); i++) {
            if (args_string[i] == ">") {
                redirectout = true;
                filename = args_string.back();
                args_char.erase(args_char.end() - 3, args_char.end());
                break;
            }
            if (args_string[i] == "<") {
                redirectin = true;
                filename = args_string.back();
                args_char.erase(args_char.end() - 3, args_char.end());
                break;
            }
        }

        if (redirectin == true && redirectout == true)
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid redirection.");
    }
};
```

As I have mentioned in the description, I'm creating a simple shell that can handle multiple pipes and, in the future, redirects.

Someone else's opinion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What *does* it do? And if you think the definition of `Command` would be helpful, you'd be right.

Comment: You haven't described exactly how you expect your program to operate, but it's important to understand that if the exec succeeds in running the new program in the child process, that child process's original code is completely replaced with the new program. Therefore there's no way for it to start up another program, which instead must be done by the parent. But you have the parent waiting. So it seems that only the first program is actually started. Your pipe handling seems overly complex, too.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I just updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are:

1. You are waiting for `ls` to complete before you launch `sort`.
2. You are closing all the pipes in the parent before you launch `sort`.

In the `for` loop, you only do the child processing; the parent needs to loop back and launch the next child.

After the `for` loop, you need to close the pipes in the parent. Then you need a loop to collect the corpses of both child processes (noting that if the shell previously started some processes running in the background, there may be a number of corpses other than the ones from the current pipeline before the current pipeline completes).

Also note that the correct place to report errors is `cerr`, not `cout`.

```
void execute(std::vector<Command *> cmds)
{
    int inp[2], out[2];  // Correct use of 2
    if (pipe(inp) != 0 || pipe(out) != 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create pipes."); // may leak descriptors
    int status, fd = 0;
    bool switcher = true;
    pid_t pids[2];  // Inappropriate use of 2

    for (auto i = 0; i < cmds.size(); i++)
    {
        auto pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1)
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not fork.");
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                dup2(inp[1], 1);
            else if (i == cmds.size() - 1)
                dup2(out[0], 0);
            else if (switcher)
            {
                dup2(inp[0], 0);
                dup2(out[1], 1);
                switcher = false;
            }
            else
            {
                dup2(inp[1], 1);
                dup2(out[0], 0);
                switcher = true;
            }

            close(inp[0]);
            close(inp[1]);
            close(out[0]);
            close(out[1]);

            execvp(cmds[i]->args_char[0], cmds[i]->args_char.data();
            std::cerr << "Command not found." << std::endl;
            exit(1);
            }
        }
        else
            pids[i] = pid;
        //} else {
        //    close(inp[0]);
        //    close(inp[1]);
        //    close(out[0]);
        //    close(out[1]);
        //    wait(&status);
        }
    }

    // Children launched - wait for the kids to die (morbid business!)
    close(inp[0]);
    close(inp[1]);
    close(out[0]);
    close(out[1]);

    int corpse;
    int kids = 2;  // Inappropriate use of 2
    while (kids > 0 && (corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kids; i++)
        {
            if (corpse == pids[i])
            {
                for (j = i+1; j < kids; j++)
                     pids[i++] = pids[j];
                kids--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's probably a better way to handle the `wait()` loop in C++ with a `vector<pid_t> kids` and suitable STL algorithms applied to it, but that's an exercise for you.  The code shown has the assumption 'there are two child processes' hardwired into it at a couple of points (marked); you'd need to sort those out for the more general case of N processes in the pipeline, and the vector should help with that, too.

Note that if an exception is thrown, the pipes are not closed.  This leaks resources. Further, if the first process is launched but the second fork fails, you've got a process that (probably) won't die because its input pipes is still open in the parent process.  A robust program would need to fix this.

---

<sup>*Warning: the code has not been passed through a compiler; there could easily be problems.*</sup>

---

Oh Futz! When there are two commands in a pipeline (as in "ls | sort"), there is only one pipe needed.  I got suckered by the code in the question!

I cleaned out much of the junk that wasn't needed for the "ls | sort" case, in both `struct Command` and the `execute()` function.  I derived a basic `main()` that hard-codes the command to be executed.  This leads to an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Command
{
    std::vector<char *> args_char;

    Command(std::vector<char *> cmds_char)
    {
        args_char = cmds_char;
    }
};

void execute(std::vector<Command *> cmds)
{
    int inp[2];
    if (pipe(inp) != 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create pipes.");
    pid_t pids[2];  // Inappropriate use of 2

    for (auto i = 0U; i < cmds.size(); i++)
    {
        auto pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1)
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not fork.");
        else if (pid == 0)
        {
            std::cerr << i << ": PID " << (int)getpid() << "\n";
            if (i == 0)
            {
                std::cerr << i << ": DUP 1\n";
                dup2(inp[1], 1);
            }
            else if (i == cmds.size() - 1)
            {
                std::cerr << i << ": DUP 2\n";
                dup2(inp[0], 0);
            }

            close(inp[0]);
            close(inp[1]);

            std::cerr << i << ": CMD " << cmds[i]->args_char[0] << "\n";
            execlp(cmds[i]->args_char[0], cmds[i]->args_char[0], (char *)0);
            std::cerr << "Command " << cmds[i]->args_char[0] << " not found." << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            pids[i] = pid;
    }

    // Children launched - wait for the kids to die (morbid business!)
    std::cerr << "Parent: waiting for the inevitable\n";
    close(inp[0]);
    close(inp[1]);

    int status;
    int corpse;
    int kids = 2;  // Inappropriate use of 2
    while (kids > 0 && (corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "2: KID " << corpse << " status " << status << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < kids; i++)
        {
            if (corpse == pids[i])
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < kids; j++)
                    pids[i++] = pids[j];
                kids--;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cerr << "2: DONE\n";
}

int main()
{
    char prg0[] = "ls";
    char prg1[] = "sort";
    std::vector<char *> cmd0 = { prg0, 0 };
    std::vector<char *> cmd1 = { prg1, 0 };
    std::vector<Command *> cmds =
    {
        new Command(cmd0),
        new Command(cmd1),
    };
    try
    {
        execute(cmds);
    }
    catch (std::exception &bug)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << bug.what() << "thrown\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Illustrative output:

```
Parent: waiting for the inevitable
0: PID 36439
0: DUP 1
0: CMD ls
1: PID 36440
1: DUP 2
1: CMD sort
2: KID 36439 status 0
cmds
cmds.cpp
cmds.dSYM
makefile
2: KID 36440 status 0
2: DONE
```

Comment: Jonathan, I'm sorry, I'm new to this sort of stuff. Can you please go more in-depth or pinpoint my mistakes programmatically?

Comment: Well, you could take a little time to look and think about it...but I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: First of all, thank you! After you told me the two problems, I moved the pipe-closing and wait outside for loop, so that my child processes complete before proceeding. My simple input "ls | wc" produced "0 0 0". Then I copied the code modified by you, and got the same result. The strange thing is; "ls | sort" doesn't produce anything :)

Comment: This example perpetuates many of the mistakes of the original.

Comment: @ooga I've been working on this for 4 days and can't get it to work. If you figured it out, please highlight my mistakes.